# why double divison returns seemingly 'wrong' answer in python

Tags: python, logic, operators

On basic operator / and // in Python. Why 99/9.9 returns 10.0 and 99//9.9 returns 9.0?

/ - returns result in float
// - returns quotient without reminder in int

so why:

```
>>> 99/9.9
10.0
>>> 99//9.9
9.0
>>> 9.9*9.0
89.10000000000001
```

when

```
>>> 9.9*10.0
99.0
```

Answer (score 3):

// is for integer division and returns the floor of the quotient. 5//2 = 2, whereas 5/2 = 2.5. It wouldn’t make sense to use // with floats. As explained by others here, floats are inexactly represented and attempted integer division on them yields unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

9.9 can't be exactly represented as a float (although it is closer than 10^-13 so just typing 9.9 doesn't show 9.9000000001 or anything like that).  So a float created from the literal 9.9 is actually slightly greater than 9.9 and 99//9.9 is 9.  Similarly, 99%9.9 is 9.899999999999997 and not 0 as we would expect if 9.9 could be exactly represented.

Moral of the story: "//" is mostly for integers and can produce headaches when used on floats.

Answer (score 0):

That is common.

"Beware that due to the limitations of floating point arithmetic, rounding errors can cause unexpected results" from [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Operators#:%7E:text=For%20Python%202.,in%20Python%202.2%20and%20later).). In that reference you can see with all detail.